# Increment form value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several images with the class "red".

When the user clicks on any of them, a form field with the Id of "red" should be incremented.

I'm trying to write this in a way that is easy to re-use.

I can't figure out if there is a way of incrementing the form field value without using a global variable. Simply writing
    $(#red).val(++); 
doesn't do anything.

If I first declare a global variable like

```
var redAmount;
$(#red).val(redAmount++);
```

it works, but I don't like the idea of having to type the color + Amount each time I re-use this for other colors.

Which made me try to form the variable name dynamically like

```
var redAmount;
var currentColor = $(obj).attr("class"); //getting the class of the clicked element
$('#' + currentColor).val(currentColor+'Amount'++); //trying to form the variable name dynamically but failing
```

Sorry for the long explanation. What I'm trying to ask is this:

1. Can I increment the form value without a global variable
2. If not, how do I form the variable name dynamically based on the class of the clicked element

Comment: like `$('#red').val($('#red').val()+1);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the increment operator in plain-old JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("red").value++;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULKb7/)

Comment: Cool with plain javascript it works! Why won't it work with jQuery like $('#red').value++; ?

Comment: `$("#red")` returns a jQuery object which wraps DOM elements - only the element itself has the `value` property.

Comment: -1 not enough jQuery. `:)` Seriously though, `$('#red')[0].value++;` may read simpler too (even though there's a slightly performance loss).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I put wrappers in my code so it would end up looking like `get.id("red").value++` which I like best.

Answer (score 0):

Code revised with tested sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/CrjY9/25/

Are you not trying to increment the value of item you are clicking on?

```
jQuery("img").click(function () {
    jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).attr("class"))[0].value++;
});
```

Hope this helps.

This is the true JQuery way, but I guess the JavaScript value++ way is just as good, in some browsers.

Comment: It's either `this.className` or `$(this).attr("class")`.  `$(this).className` won't be defined.

Comment: @ShaunOreilly no it's more complicated than just incrementing the value of the item being clicked. Imagine 10 images of red apples and 10 images of green apples. Each time a red apple is clicked, the shopping cart has to increase the amount of red apples in it by 1. But there is not just one image of red apples but several different ones and each of them should affect the value.

Comment: Try the sample and see if it works for you, in true jQuery code